# Organizing tree copying with inheritance using C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, tree

I have a `Tree_item` class (C++/Qt4 is used, C++03 compatible), which represents a tree structure. Each node has a raw pointer to parent and `QList` of pointers to children. `Tree_item` has a copy constructor, which is called recursively and works fine.

```
Tree_item::Tree_item(const Tree_item &tree_item)
{
 //deep copy tree_item members to the current instance 
 //...

 for (unsigned int i = 0;i < tree_item.child_list_.size();i++)
 {
    Tree_item* new_child = new Tree_item(*tree_item.child_list_.at(i));
    new_child->parent_item_ = this;
    child_list_ << new_child;        
 }
}
```

But I need to create an inherited class `Extended_tree_item`, which contains some `int` and `bool` members and methods. This new class must have a constructor with a const reference to the base class instance (additional members must be set to default values). I've heard about `Prototype` design pattern, but the usage examples are primitive. How should constructors and `clone` methods be organized for a tree with base and derived classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeItem class should have:

```
virtual TreeItem *clone() const { return new TreeItem(*this); }
```

And then derived class would have:

```
virtual Extended_tree_item *clone() const {
   return new Extended_tree_item(*this);
}
```

Then extended tree item should have copy-ctor too:

```
Extended_tree_item(const Extended_tree_item &orig);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that `clone` method body is simple, the problem is when to call `clone`.

Comment: well, you call clone instead of creating new TreeItem, for example in your base class copy ctor.

Comment: Where your original code has `new Tree_item(*tree_item.child_list_.at(i))` you should instead have `tree_item.child_list_.at(i)->clone()`

Comment: But how should `Extended_tree_item(const Tree_item &orig)` be organized? I need a clone from the basic tree structure.